# Old book series about teenagers with dragon blood

Tags: story-identification, books

I had this memory about these old books I used to read in elementary school, but I can’t think of the title. It’s a book series about these teenagers who all have dragon blood or DNA or something. Each book follows a different teen, but I’m pretty sure it was all connected in some way.

Comment: Can you give us some more details like when you read this, if the books were new at the time, what the cover looked like, etc?

Comment: Some details about the plot would be appreciated too, did the teenagers had powers? Was there any sort of common goal?

Comment: If I had to say something, I'd say it is Dragonblood series, by Michael Dahl. But I'd need more details to say for sure.

Comment: Did the books take place on Earth in contemporary times? In the past? In a fantasy world?

Comment: @Roberto it sounds like [the Dragonblood series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/76823-dragonblood) to me. I would post that as an answer. Whether it's correct or not it will still be of interest to anyone reading this question.

Answer (score 6):

It might be the [Dragonblood series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/76823-dragonblood), written by Michael Dahl.

The dragons are returning, and across the world young humans are discovering that they were born with dragon blood, which gives them powers. Each book in the series narrates the adventure of a different teen, which matches your description.

Comment: yep, just googled it. That’s it, you’re a god lol. Much love!